# Why is fish not using my abbreviations.fish file?

Tags: fish

I have the following abbreviations.fish file located in `~/.config/fish/abbreviations.fish`

`abbr -a gco 'git checkout'`

But when I am in the terminal, I can use `gco`. Can I just create any `.fish` files in the fish config folder and they should be automatically loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I just create any .fish files in the fish config folder and they should be automatically loaded?

No.

You can create *function* files in ~/.config/fish/**functions** (these should contain the function they are named after, and are only loaded when that function is about to be executed).

In fish >= 2.3.0, you can put arbitrary files that will be sourced on startup into ~/.config/fish/**conf.d**/. The only restriction is that the name has to end in ".fish".

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that when I set abbreviations using the web interface, they get stored in ~/.config/fish/fish.xxxx file. Is it best practice to write those manually into config.fish, so you can, for example, track them into version control?